# Object types and accessing nested values

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm having trouble figuring out (or finding detailed enough docs that I can understand them) for the python google library, `Calendar` API.  I'm trying to figure out what methods my return object has, and how to access its data members.  I'm following the tutorial at https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/get_started under the "Authorized API for installed application example."  In the code below, I've successfully authenticated, and request a list of events.  The returned value is a JSON list of events `"items"`.  Full description of return value [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/python/latest/calendar_v3.events.html#list).

```
service = discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)

try:
    #sample from google devs, prints title of all events, ever on primary
    request = service.events().list(calendarId='primary')
    while request != None:
        response = request.execute()
        for event in response.get('items', []):
            print repr(event.get('summary', 'NO SUMMARY')) + '\n'
        request = service.events().list_next(request, response)'''
```

I'm having trouble accessing member data in the for loop.  'summary' is a top level data member of `event` from 'items', and is only a string.  'creator' is a dictionary, with a value `displayName` I want to print.  If I try something like `print repr(event.get('creator') + '\n'`, it prints the dictionary 'creator'.  If I try `print repr(event.get'creator["displayName"]'), it always prints None.  I solved the problem by doing:

```
creator = event.get('creator')
print str(creator['displayName']) + '\n'
```

but I think I'm missing some kind of syntax that will allow me to access the inner values all in one line.  The other thing is, I don't understand what kind of object `event` is inside the loop.  I mean, obviously its an `event` object returned from the request, but the only API documentation I can find refers to the object created by `service.events()`.  This event.get() method is a different one than the one in the docs (at least, it has different args), but I don't know where to find that documentation.

TL;DR
Syntax for accessing dictionary value in an event from the returned list
Where to find the method descriptions/docs for an event from the returned list

Comment: Have you tried `dir(event)`? That will return a list of all the methods/attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objects in the response are dictionaries, and should support all of the [same methods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict). It's often easiest to use bracket notation to access the properties of the object.

```
print event['creator']['displayName']
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't seen that notation with dictionaries yet, and I couldn't even figure out what that was anyway, great answer.